# Laravel test kept failing due to wrong method

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following test to check my simple crud application in laravel.

I have my SalesManagersTest.php in tests/features

```
<?php

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;
 
class SalesManagersTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
 
    public function test_can_see_index_screen()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/salesmanagers');
 
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
    
    public function test_can_see_add_record_screen()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/salesmanagers/create');
 
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
 
    public function test_can_add_new_record()
    {
        $response = $this->POST('/salesmanagers/create', [
            '_token' => csrf_token(),
            'full_name' => 'Test User',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'telephone' => '0775678999',
            'current_route' => 'Negombo',
            'joined_date'=>'2022/09/12',
            'comments' => 'Test comment'
        ]);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertRedirectedTo('salesmanagers');
    }
}
```

The first two tests work well but the third test is giving  me an error

but since I'm trying to insert new record the method has to be POST

this is my web.php

```
Route::get('/', [ SalesManagersController::class, 'index' ]);
Route::resource('salesmanagers',  SalesManagersController::class);
Route::get('salesmanagers.create', [ SalesManagersController::class, 'create' ]);
Route::post('salesmanagers.create', [ SalesManagersController::class, 'store' ]);
```

What could be the the issue with my test?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `route` definition. It appears you're using a `route` name for the `URI` of your route. Change your `route` to the following and try again:

```
Route::post('/salesmanagers', [SalesManagersController::class, 'store']);
```

Oh and `POST` your data to `/salesmanagers` not `salesmanagers/create`.